# MSBuild task silent execution

Tags: msbuild, output, task

I have msbuild script that perfectly working. But when it runs when build task executed I'm seeing all output of building progress. 
Is there a way to just write :

Building project  ... OK.

instead of 1000 rows of text?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [verbosity parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) to set log to the level you'd like, e.g.:

```
msbuild myScript.proj /verbosity:quiet
```

---

**UPD:**

Sorry, that was not clear from the original question, but (from the comments) it looks like you want to have different verbosity levels for different Tasks. I don't think this is supported out-of-the box. You could try 2 solutions:

1. Run your task using Exec task (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865656/how-to-change-verbosity-of-the-msbuild-task) for details)
2. Implement [a custom logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471.aspx) and filter messages by task name.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, but I call build as task from xml. I need other task write to log, as <Message Text="bla"/>. but not <MSBuild> task

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear from the original question: it looks like you want to have different verbosity levels for different Tasks. I've updated the answer with the options I see